# AdventureWorks presentation

Tags: database, adventureworks

I want to implement an application (scholar exercise) over the AdventureWorks database. I have downloaded the diagram. Is there a less formal description of the database?

Thanks,
Lucian

Answer (score 1):

found it: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms124659.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Adventure Works Cycles Business Scenarios
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms124825.aspx

HTH